# Lambda call two functions from one interface

Tags: java, interface, lambda

```
interface MathOperation{
    int operation1(int a, int b);
    int operation2(int c, int d, int e);
}

public static int operate1(int a, int b, MathOperation mathOperation){
    return mathOperation.operation1(a, b);
}

public static int operate2(int a, int b, int c, MathOperation mathOperation){
    return mathOperation.operation2(a, b, c);
}
```

Why does the following code not work?

```
System.out.println("5 - 3 = " + operate1(5, 3, (a,b)->a-b));
System.out.println("5 + 3 + 4 = " + operate2(5, 3, 4, (a,b,c)->a+b+c));
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: lets try from another side: why this code should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JLS 9.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) says this (paraphrased):

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method. Instances of functional interfaces can be created with lambda expressions.

Since `MathOperation` has more than one method, it cannot be created with a lambda expression.

Why can't that be? Well, because if we did this:

```
operate2( 1, 2, 3, ( (a, b) -> a + b ) );
```

What should happen, since we did not supply a definition of `operation2`?

---

Use of the [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation will warn you of this, similar to how the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation works:

```
/* causes a compilation error because
   MathOperation is not a functional interface */
@FunctionalInterface
interface MathOperation {
    int operation1(int a, int b);
    int operation2(int c, int d, int e);
}
```

A more canonical definition of your sample code would be:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntTernaryOperator {
    int applyAsInt(int a, int b, int c);
}

public static int operate1(
    int a, int b,
    IntBinaryOperator op
) {
    return op.applyAsInt(a, b);
}

public static int operate2(
    int a, int b, int c,
    IntTernaryOperator op
) {
    return op.applyAsInt(a, b, c);
}
```

JSE supplies a binary int operation, [`java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html), but not a ternary operation, so we need to define our own.